# Is it possible to specify a date type to use?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm currently working on a fairly complicated chart for a report with [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/).

The data that is given to the graph changes depending on various filters that are given to the report. For example, a user can specify that they want to look at the report for a specific day, week or month, from there they can also control the graph to show either a year overview or an overview of whatever period they're looking at.

The problem I'm encountering is with the labels on the x axis. As another example; if a user is looking at the year overview on the week time period there shall be 53 points of data on the graph, however this is labelled by month. I need this to be labelled by week number in steps of 2, just the number is fine.

I have already found the date formatter for week numbers and uncommented it in `highcharts.src.js`. So I just need a way to specific a date format to use i.e. day, week, month etc.

The only thing I've been able to find of any use so far (that hasn't done anything) is [this section](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats) on the x axis part of the API:

```
{
    second: '%H:%M:%S',
    minute: '%H:%M',
    hour: '%H:%M',
    day: '%e. %b',
    week: '%e. %b', // This one here, how do I specify when to use this?
    month: '%b \'%y',
    year: '%Y'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need your custom filter, then you can use setExtremes() function http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes.

To define labels you can use formatter() http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.formatter

But I assume that you mean about ticks which should be positioned dinamically i.e by tickPositioner() http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositioner